How to quickly hide all the extensions in Chrome for the purpose of recording and screensharing?
Screensharing. Recording. Long long long list of Chrome extensions. I don't want entire world to see it.
There are some workarounds:

manually hide
use another browser profile

But that's not convenient. I don't want to manually hide and then pin it again. I don't want to copy-paste open URLs, reaarrange windows, log in to various websites (sometimes the content I'm sharing is behind a login).
Looking for simple button: "hide all extensions", just like you hide a dock or top bar (on Mac)

I recommend (another) extension called "Extension Manager" for this.
It has a setting to turn off all extensions with 2 clicks:

Click the Extension icon
Move the cursor to "Default", then when the rest of options popup, click "All Off"


I also recommend that you first create the set containing the extensions you want to turn on as the "Default."  When you're done, just follow the same steps but choose the "Default" set.
